# Filtering portfolio with Isotope

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-isotope

I got some trouble using Isotope. I'm creating a video-portfolio for myself. In fact, I do Camera jobs, lighting, editing and grading. I would like to be able to sort them with 4 checkboxes in a exclusive combination.
But, if i check Camera and Grading for exemple, it returns nothing. I think it's a problem with my ***"data-category"*** and my return in my JS script.

Thank you for reading and helping!

index.html

```
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <img src="images/logo_mxm.png"/>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <input id="checkbox-camera" class="checkbox-custom" type="checkbox" value="camera" />
                <label for="checkbox-camera" class="checkbox-custom-label">CAMERA</label>
            </ul>

            <ul>
                <input id="checkbox-light" class="checkbox-custom" type="checkbox" value="light" />
                <label for="checkbox-light" class="checkbox-custom-label">LIGHT</label>
            </ul>

            <ul>
                <input id="checkbox-edit" class="checkbox-custom" type="checkbox" value="edit" />
                <label for="checkbox-edit" class="checkbox-custom-label">EDIT</label>
            </ul>

            <ul>
                <input id="checkbox-grading" class="checkbox-custom" type="checkbox" value="grading" />
                <label for="checkbox-grading" class="checkbox-custom-label">GRADING</label>
            </ul>
        </li>    
    </div>

        <div id="container">
            <div class="item" data-category="camera light grading all">
                <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OsuD2Ec7zjE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                <p>Suedama | Au-dessus</p>
                <div class="rond" id="rond_camera"></div>
                <div class="rond" id="rond_light"></div>
                <div class="rond" id="rond_grading"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="item" data-category="camera light edit grading all">
                <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/201592536?color=263e69&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
                <p>Je suis l&#039;ultime combat</p>
                <div class="rond" id="rond_camera"></div>
                <div class="rond" id="rond_light"></div>
                <div class="rond" id="rond_edit"></div>
                <div class="rond" id="rond_grading"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="item" data-category="light all">
                <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ypL1MCq9aJQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                <p>Enovos | Professeur House</p>
                <div class="rond" id="rond_light"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="item" data-category="light all">
                <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5QDSi4VuEJE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                <p>Bernard Massard signature | 4 Artistes</p>
                <div class="rond" id="rond_light"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="item" data-category="camera light edit grading all">
                <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/168194761?color=e3cc39&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
                <p>Tom à la ferme #2</p>
                <div class="rond" id="rond_camera"></div>
                <div class="rond" id="rond_light"></div>
                <div class="rond" id="rond_edit"></div>
                <div class="rond" id="rond_grading"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="item" data-category="camera light edit grading all">
                <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/129125561?color=e3cc39&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
                <p>Tom à la ferme #1</p>
                <div class="rond" id="rond_camera"></div>
                <div class="rond" id="rond_light"></div>
                <div class="rond" id="rond_edit"></div>
                <div class="rond" id="rond_grading"></div>
            </div>

        </div>

    <!--Javascript-->
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://npmcdn.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js'></script>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>


</body>
```

index.js

```
// set up variables
var categoryFilters = [];
var categoryFilter;

// init Isotope
var $container = $('#container').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.item',
  filter: function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    categoryFilter = categoryFilters.length ? categoryFilters.join(' ') : 'all';
    console.log(categoryFilter);
    var categoryResult = categoryFilter ? $this.is('[data-category*=' + categoryFilter + ']') : true;
    return categoryResult;
  }
});

// filter with checkboxes
var $checkboxes = $('#menu input');

$checkboxes.change( function() {
  categoryFilters.length = 0;
  $checkboxes.each( function( i, elem ) {
    if ( elem.checked ) {
      categoryFilters.push( elem.value );
      console.log('check');
    }
    $container.isotope();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your checkbox values need to have a "." before the value , i.e `<input id="checkbox-edit" class="checkbox-custom" type="checkbox" value=".edit" />`. (see below)
 Also, your unordered list html is backwards, with a bunch of `<ul>`'s between one `<li>`. It should be:

```
<ul>
        <li>
            <input id="checkbox-camera" class="checkbox-custom" type="checkbox" value=".camera" />
            <label for="checkbox-camera" class="checkbox-custom-label">CAMERA</label>
        </li>

        <li>
            <input id="checkbox-light" class="checkbox-custom" type="checkbox" value=".light" />
            <label for="checkbox-light" class="checkbox-custom-label">LIGHT</label>
        </li>

        <li>
            <input id="checkbox-edit" class="checkbox-custom" type="checkbox" value=".edit" />
            <label for="checkbox-edit" class="checkbox-custom-label">EDIT</label>
        </li>

        <li>
            <input id="checkbox-grading" class="checkbox-custom" type="checkbox" value=".grading" />
            <label for="checkbox-grading" class="checkbox-custom-label">GRADING</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

A jsfiddle or link would help see things in a better way.